# Django filter data in a form to another view

Tags: django, django-forms, django-filter

I can't seem to get this right, and I have viewed almost every like post. And now I have no clue what my code is doing. I have an index page, that has a small form. I just want to use this form to query my db and filter the results. I used django-filters on another page, and it works perfectly, but I can't seem to pass the data from my index page's form to the next view. Here is my code:

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import IndexView
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('search/', views.search, name='search'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.db.models import Max, Min
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import FormView

from .filters import ProductFilter
from .forms import ProductSearchForm
from .models import LengthRange, Hull, PowerConfiguration, SpeedRange, Product


class IndexView(FormView):
    template_name = 'index.html'
    form_class = ProductSearchForm
    success_url = "search/"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['length_ranges'] = LengthRange.objects.all().order_by('pk')
        context['hull_types'] = Hull.objects.all().order_by('pk')
        context['power_configs'] = PowerConfiguration.objects.all().order_by('pk')
        context['speed_ranges'] = SpeedRange.objects.all().order_by('pk')
        context['price'] = Product.objects.all().aggregate(Min('price'), Max('price'))
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # This method is called when valid form data has been POSTed.
        # It should return an HttpResponse.
        # form.send_email()
        # print "form is valid"
        return super(IndexView, self).form_valid(form)


def search(request):
    product_list = Product.objects.all()
    product_filter = ProductFilter(request.GET, queryset=product_list)
    return render(request, 'product_list.html', {'filter': product_filter})
```

**forms.py**

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Product


class ProductSearchForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('length_range', 'hull_type', 'price', 'power', 'speed', 'hull_only_available')
```

**product_list.html**

```
{% load humanize %}
<html>
<form method="get">
    {{ filter.form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
  </form>
  <ul>
  {% for product in filter.qs %}
    <li>{{ product.vendor }} {{ product.product_model }} - ${{ product.price|intcomma }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
  </ul>
</html>
```

**index.html**

```
<form class="nl-form" action="{% url 'boatsales:search' %}" method="post">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                                A boat with a length of
                                <select>
                                    <option value="*" selected>any size</option>
                                    {% for length in length_ranges %}
                                        <option value="{{ length.pk }}">{{ length.range }}</option>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </select>
                                , with hull type of
                                <select>
                                    <option value="*" selected>any</option>
                                    {% for hull in hull_types %}
                                        <option value="{{ hull.pk }}">{{ hull.type }}</option>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </select>
                                with
                                <select>
                                    <option value="*" selected>any</option>
                                    {% for power in power_configs %}
                                        <option value="{{ power.pk }}">a {{ power.configuration }}</option>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </select>
                                power
                                configuration and a top speed between
                                <select>
                                    <option value="*" selected>any MPH</option>
                                    {% for speed in speed_ranges %}
                                        <option value="{{ speed.pk }}">{{ speed.range }} MPH</option>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </select>.
                                My budget is from <input type="text" value="{{ price.price__min|intword }}"
                                                         placeholder="{{ price.price__min|intword }}"
                                                         data-subline="Our current lowest price is: <em>{{ price__min|intword }}</em>"/>
                                to
                                <input
                                        type="text" value="{{ price.price__max|intword }}"
                                        placeholder="{{ price.price__min|intword }}"
                                        data-subline="Our current highest price is: <em>{{ price.price__min|intword }}</em>"/>
                                and hull only
                                availability <select>
                                <option value="False" selected>is not</option>
                                <option value="True">is</option>
                            </select> a concern.
                                <div class="container">
                                    <button type="submit"
                                            class="btn-a btn-a_size_large btn-a_color_theme">
                                        Show me the results!
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
```

I know this looks like a complete mess right now, because I'm getting different advice from multiple sources. I just can't seem to get the functionality correct.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here I think is that the form is posting its data to the `search()` view, but that view is using `request.GET` when transferring the data to the `ProductFilter`, and `request.GET` will be empty.

Pass `request.POST` instead:

```
product_filter = ProductFilter(request.POST, queryset=product_list)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that isn't the issue. Django-filter only works with get requests. I'll need to pass the results from the first form as a get request, but I havne't been able to do that so far. Just spent an hour reading the docs for django-filter and found that out.

Answer (score 0):

Had to modify my IndexView and my form, but it now passes the values via a get request and pass the kwargs to the next view. Here is the current code:

**form.py**

```
class ProductSearchForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProductSearchForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['length_range'].empty_label = "any size"
        self.fields['hull_type'].empty_label = "any type"
        self.fields['power'].empty_label = "any type"
        self.fields['speed'].empty_label = "any speed"
        self.fields['hull_only_available'].empty_label = None
        # self.fields['price'].widget.attrs['min'] = Product.price
        # self.fields['price'].widget.attrs['max'] = Product.price

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('length_range', 'hull_type', 'price', 'power', 'speed', 'hull_only_available')
```

**views.py**

```
class IndexView(FormView):
    template_name = 'index.html'
    form_class = ProductSearchForm
    success_url = "search/"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['length_ranges'] = LengthRange.objects.all().order_by('pk')
        context['hull_types'] = Hull.objects.all().order_by('pk')
        context['power_configs'] = PowerConfiguration.objects.all().order_by('pk')
        context['speed_ranges'] = SpeedRange.objects.all().order_by('pk')
        context['price'] = Product.objects.all().aggregate(Min('price'), Max('price'))
        return context

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(IndexView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        return kwargs
```